# nonetype issue and also username variable issue

Tags: python

These are my two def functions:

```
def valid_username(username):
     # implement the function here


    while True:

        try:
            username = input("Username: ")


            if len(username) < 8:
                print ("Sorry, the username must be at least 8 characters long.")


            if username.isalnum() == False:
                print ("Sorry, your name can only contain alpha numeric characters")


            numupper = 0


            for c in username:

                if c.isupper() == True:
                    numupper += 1

            if numupper > 0:
                print ("You have at least 1 uppercase in this username.")

            else:
                print ("You have no uppercase in this username.")

            numlower = 0

            for d in username:

                if d.islower() == True:
                    numlower +=1
            if numlower > 0:
                print ("You have at least 1 lowercase in this username.")

            else:
                print ("You have no lowercase in this username.")


            numdigit = 0

            for e in username:

                if e.isdigit() == True:
                    numdigit += 1
            if numdigit > 0:
                print ("You have at least one digit in this username.")

            else:
                print("You have no digits in this username.")

                continue

        except:
            print ("Sorry, not valid. Try again.")
        else:
            print ("Thank you for your input")
            break


def valid_password(password, username):
    # implement the function here

    while True:

        try:
            password = input("Password: ")

            if username in password:
                print ("That's not secure at all.")



            if len(password) < 8:
                print ("Sorry, the password must be at least 8 characters long.")


            if password.isalnum() == False:
                print ("Sorry, your password can only contain alpha numeric characters")


            numupper = 0


            for c in password:

                if c.isupper() == True:
                    numupper += 1

            if numupper > 0:
                print ("You have at least 1 uppercase in this password.")

            else:
                print ("You have no uppercase in this password.")

            numlower = 0

            for d in password:

                if d.islower() == True:
                    numlower +=1
            if numlower > 0:
                print ("You have at least 1 lowercase in this password.")

            else:
                print ("You have no lowercase in this password.")


            numdigit = 0

            for e in password:

                if e.isdigit() == True:
                    numdigit += 1
            if numdigit > 0:
                print ("You have at least one digit in this password.")

            else:
                print("You have no digits in this password.")

                continue

        except:
            print ("Sorry, not valid. Try again.")
        else:
            print ("Thank you for your input")
            break
```

my main program is this:

```
username = input("Username: ")


result, reason = uservalidation.valid_username(username)


if not(result):
    print (reason)


else:

    password = input("Password: ")


    pwresult, pwreason = uservalidation.valid_password(password, username)


    if not(pwresult):
        print (pwreason)
    else:
        print ("Username and Password combination is valid!")
```

when I run it I get the following:

```
Username: d
Username: user
Sorry, the username must be at least 8 characters long.
You have no uppercase in this username.
You have at least 1 lowercase in this username.
You have no digits in this username.
Username: craig2345
You have no uppercase in this username.
You have at least 1 lowercase in this username.
You have at least one digit in this username.
Thank you for your input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Si Hong/Desktop/pythontest/HuangSiHong_Assign8_part3.py", line 7, in <module>
    result, reason = uservalidation.valid_username(username)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
>>>
```

I'm having trouble figuring out why when I type enter in the first value for username, it doesn't trigger the function, but does it after the 2nd time I enter it in, and also I am not sure how to solve the nonetype error issue, if someone can explain this to me, that would be great thank you so much!

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a function doesn't have a value explicitly returned then it implicitly returns `None`, which cannot be applied to tuple unpacking this way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're seeing the `Username:` prompt twice is that you ask for input once in the main program and then again, immediately, inside the function.  The function should not ask the user for any input, it gets the value of username from the argument passed to it.

The reason you're seeing the error about NoneType (not nonetype as you wrote, Python is case-sensitive and you should really get in the habit of typing exactly what it says) is that your function valid_password() does finish with a return statement returning two values as expected by your program. In fact, it doesn't have a return statement at all, which means it effectively returns the special Python value None (which is an object of type NoneType).

Because you tell your program to extract *two* values from whatever the function returns, it's trying to do so by *iterating* over the values returned.  NoneType is not one of the types that can be iterated over (since it contains no information), thus the error message.